# Obtain NH-adjusted p values for a list of tests

Tags: r, lapply

I have a number of tests I need to run like so:

```
kruskal.test(choice_qset ~ outcome, data=d, na.action = na.omit)
```

I am storing the variable names in variable like so:

```
choice_qset<-c("var1","var2","var3")
```

and then I'd like to store the p values for the whole list in order to adjust them with p.adjust.

I tried this:

```
models <- lapply(choice_qset, function(x) {
    kruskal.test(substitute(i ~ outcome, list(i = as.name(x))), data=d, na.action = na.omit)
})
```

then I could adjust ps taken from models[[]][3].
However it does not work, says:

```
Error in kruskal.test.default(substitute(i ~ outcome, list(i = as.name(x))),  : 
  argument "g" is missing, with no default
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because if you specific a formula, you need a data.frame.

I am guessing you have `var1 var2` and `var3` floating around in the environment. It's easier if you put all of them into a data.frame. I have to simulate data for var1,var2,var3 and outcome since you did not provide it:

```
var1 = factor(rbinom(100,1,0.5))
var2 = factor(rbinom(100,1,0.4))
var3 = factor(rbinom(100,1,0.3))
outcome = runif(100)
df = data.frame(var1,var2,var3,outcome)
```

We run the test:

```
test = lapply(c("var1","var2","var3"),function(i){
kruskal.test(reformulate(i,"outcome"),data=df)
})

names(test) = c("var1","var2","var3")
```

To get the p-values:

```
sapply(test,"[[","p.value")
     var1      var2      var3 
0.3586017 0.1962014 0.9855856
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, thanks:

```
formulas <- paste(choice_qset, "outcome", sep = " ~ ")
res <- lapply(formulas, function(f)  kruskal.test(as.formula(f),data=d, na.action = na.omit))
```